# Issues in rendering choice type: Array to string conversion

Tags: laravel, symfony, doctrine, twig

I am trying to have a simple dropdown with 2 options (`admin`,`csr`) in a form, so that the user be able to update the `role` if necessary. There is no problem when I use a text type and I am able to change and update the value (in DB):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('number', TextType::class, [
                'disabled' => true
            ])
            ->add('code')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('access_level');
    }
```

<kbd>Twig</kbd>

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon hidden-sm">Access Level</span>
    {{ form_widget(form.access_level) }}
</div>
```

But when I change it to be displayed as a dropdown, it's throwing an error as follows:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Array to string conversion").
>   in form_div_layout.html.twig (line 82)

What am I missing in here:

```
....
->add('name')
->add('access_level', ChoiceType::class, array(
     'choices' => array(
          'admin' => 'Admin', 
          'csr' => 'CSR'),
 ) );
```

<kbd>twig: (no changes)</kbd>

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon hidden-sm">Access Level</span>
    {{ form_widget(form.access_level) }}
</div>
```

also here is the column type in the entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column()
 * @JMS\SerializedName("access_level")
 * @JMS\Type("string")
 */
protected $access_level;
```

---

I changed the form builder like this:

```
->add('access_level', ChoiceType::class, array( 
        'choices' => array('admin', 'csr'), 
        'choices_as_values' => true,
```

and it's working now, but it's showing the keys in the dropdown instead of choices! Even after I added 'choices_as_values' => true, it doesn't fix however the choice is stored in the db when I edit the form! Do you have any idea how can I fix it?
Here is the screenshot of what I get:

[image]

Comment: Try to use this : `{{ implode('',form_widget(form.access_level))  }} `

Comment: @Deepen, what? Just no...

Comment: @Kmaj I used choice the same way you are trying, please check form_widget block in form_div_layout.html.twig

Comment: @Deepen, it's giving a syntax error.

Comment: @habibun, thank you for your reply, what should I change in form_widget block of form_div_layout.html.twig (the error is from line 82 of this file).  <option value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if choice.attr %}{% with { attr: choice.attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}{% endif %}{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ choice_translation_domain is same as(false) ? choice.label : choice.label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}</option>

Answer (score 0):

That is really weird and confusing. If I put anything in the **key** of *choices* array other than "Admin", it works fine!

```
->add('access_level', ChoiceType::class, array(
     'choices' => array('whateveradfafafa' => 'admin', 'CSR' => 'csr'),
```

But if I change the key to "Admin" it throws ("Array to string conversion") error!

```
->add('access_level', ChoiceType::class, array(
     'choices' => array('Admin' => 'admin', 'CSR' => 'csr'),
```

---

So I fixed it by adding a space at the end "admin "!

Does anyone have any idea why it's happening?